# let doesn't work when used with -XRankNTypes

Tags: haskell, let, rank-n-types

Consider the following minimal example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

module Test where

class C w

data A = A (forall u. C u => u)

x :: forall u. C u => u
x = undefined

a = A x
```

This typechecks fine, as expected. However, if `a` is refactored to use a `let` statement:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

module Test where

class C w

data A = A (forall u. C u => u)

x :: forall u. C u => u
x = undefined

a = let x' = x in A x'
```

It suddenly fails to typecheck with the following error:

```
test.hs:12:14: error:
    * No instance for (C u0) arising from a use of `x'
    * In the expression: x
      In an equation for x': x' = x
      In the expression: let x' = x in A x'
   |
12 | a = let x' = x in A x'
   |              ^

test.hs:12:21: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `u' with actual type `u0'
        because type variable `u' would escape its scope
      This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall u. C u => u
        at test.hs:12:19-22
    * In the first argument of `A', namely x'
      In the expression: A x'
      In the expression: let x' = x in A x'
    * Relevant bindings include x' :: u0 (bound at test.hs:12:9)
   |
12 | a = let x' = x in A x'
```

Why is this happening? Doesn't this violate equational reasoning?

Comment: Monomorphism restriction strikes again.

Comment: Yes - enabling `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` suddenly makes it work- thank you!

Comment: @n.m. - do you want to turn this into an answer?

Comment: I have tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of the dreaded monomorphism restriction. Enabling `XNoMonomorphismRestriction` should cause this to compile.

`a = let x' = x in A x'` is *not* equivalent to `a = A x`, because under monomorphism restriction `x'` in `let x' = ...` is monomorphic, but A requires a polymorphic argument.